# Linear Transformation Explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I think I have a very basic thing I don't understand. Here are the details:

[image: question]

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: do you not understand how the matrix $A$ representing a linear transformation $T$ with respect to the standard basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is computed?

Comment: @abel, no I do not understand, which is very bad, I know...

Comment: @Alan What is **your** definition of "matrix representing a linear function wrt some basis"? As far as I see this is just the definition of this concept.

Comment: @Timbuc  don't understand why it's the matrix after performing the T transformation. I might not understand the definition.

Comment: You have to apply the transformation on the given basis (in this case, the standard one) and write the outcome as a linera combination of that matrix, and then take the **transpose** of the resulting coefficients matrix...do you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will try. given a transformation $T$ from $R^2 \to R^2$ by $T(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 + ax_2, bx_2),$  the matrix $A$ representing $T$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix that satisfies $\pmatrix{x_1+ax_2\\bx_2} = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}$ for all $x_1, x_2.$

now, if you set $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0,$ you get $\pmatrix{1\\0} = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}}\pmatrix{1\\0} = \pmatrix{a_{11}\\a_{21}}$ that gives you the first column of $A.$

if you set $x_2 = 1, x_2 = 1,$ you get $\pmatrix{a\\b} = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}}\pmatrix{0\\1} = \pmatrix{a_{21}\\a_{22}}$ that gives you the second column of $A.$

finally, $$ A = \pmatrix{1&a\\0&b}.$$